# List select from another list with regex

Tags: python, list

My code works, but an one-liner (`map`, `filter`, `zip` or anything else) would be a nicer solution

```
form_win = ['2/5','1/4','3/2','4/1','5/8','1/3','7/10','8/6']
form_chr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

b=[]
for cnt, a in enumerate(form_win):
    if re.match(r'^1\/', a) != None:
        b.extend(form_chr[cnt])
print ('uglyst:',b)
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Does this work as your for loop?` [ form_chr[cnt] for cnt, a in enumerate(form_win) if re.match(r'^1\/', a) != None ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using map, filter and zip

```
b = list(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: re.match(r'^1\/', x[0]) != None, zip(form_win,form_chr))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
b = [form_chr[cnt] for cnt, a in enumerate(form_win) if re.match(r'^1\/', a) is not None]
```

Comment: Oh this is what i want , perfect. Thank You :)

Comment: Thank again Cleb, am newbie in Stackoverflow, but love it

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code as follows:

```
import re

form_win = ['2/5','1/4','3/2','4/1','5/8','1/3','7/10','8/6']
form_chr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

print('uglyst:',[ form_chr[cnt]  for cnt, a in enumerate(form_win) if(re.match(r'^1\/', a))])
```